# Any way to retrieve lost iPod photos?

Tags: icloud, photos, ipod

Okay, here's the story: I lost my beloved iPod touch at school one day and never found it again.  I desperately want those photos back, but I can't recall ever having backed up any photos or anything on it.  I know the login information for the iCloud that I had set up for it and I was wondering if there's absolutely any way that I could retrieve those photos.  If not, I guess I'll live with it, but those were really important and I gotta know if there's some way to get em back.

Comment: log into icloud.com and see what's there in photos, also if iCloud backup was enabled they may be included in a backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't back up the photos, they're gone, sadly.

If you connected the iPod to the computer, iTunes may have backed them up without you realizing it, So check there first.

If you enabled iPod backups, you can send iPod on any other device and manage the storage to see if the iPod has a backup. If so, you can restore that back up on to pretty much any device.